# Delicious API or Feed - pagination

Tags: json, api, rss, feed, delicious-api

I am trying to get all or at least many bookmarks for a given tag out of delicious. I remember that it was possible to use pagination in earlier version of the delicious feed mechanics.

But I was astonished to see that pagination does not seem to work any longer.
Is there any way for me to acquire many bookmarks given a specific tag or is there no chance?

Thanks for the help
Philipp